# Secondary SSL Certificate on same IIS application

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

On Azure web apps, there is a default SSL certificate signed by Azure. If you add a custom domain and a certificate for that domain the Azure certificate still exists and it is visible with ssl checker https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/. This is something that suite me for a specific application.

How can I do the same thing on an o premise server with Windows 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5? I want to have 2 certificates for the same domain. Is this possible?

Comment: Title is not what you ask later.

Comment: 2 certificates for the same domain? What purpose would that serve? That is just a waste of money if you are buying the certificates. Besides, I think you are seeing 2 certificates on SSLtest because of SNI... you need to be more clear on what exactly you want in your question.

Comment: the problem is that the application works perfectly with all browsers with the current certificate but some old IoT devices are not capable to handle this certificate because they do not support SHA384 that our certificate chain have. so we need to add a second self signed certificate with no chain as Azure default certificate

Comment: It is not a secondary certificate like you described, but an IP based mapping that serves as fallback, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you ware asking for, but here are (SSL) binding in a nutshell:

- You can have *one* certificate for *one* binding (=site) in IIS (like in azure)
- You can have as many bindings (=sites) as you like
- Multiple bindings (=sites) pointing to the same application is possible
- Each binding (=site) can have different certificates (this is what azure does, it's just IIS reverse proxy sites, each with a ssl binding)
- Bindings (=sites) can be bound to protocol, IP, port and SNI (if using https, hostheaders if using http)
- It does not matter if the IIS is running in azure or on premise, both are capable of multiple sites with different bindings
- This is even possible with IIS as reverse proxy with multiple sites, if you need to use just one backend

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is perfectly clear. Summing up each binding can have 1 certificate. for example mydomain.com can have certificate 1 and www.mydomain.com can have certificate 2. But how the same binding at Azure displays 2 certificates in SSLLabs?

Comment: It shouldn't ne able to do that, except it's using a chain with multiple certs. Do you have a URL to check for that?